# No such slot message with QtPublish&Subscribe

Tags: c++, qt

My QValueSpaceSubscriber cannot find the public slot datachanged I created for some reason,

```
  public slots: void datachanged();

  suc = new QValueSpaceSubscriber ("/Allstar/external/", this);
```

QObject::connect(suc, SIGNAL( contentsChanged()),this,
                    SLOT( datachanged();) );

I always get this message:

[Qt Message] Object::connect: No such slot ExternalAccess::datachanged();

```
ExternalAccess::ExternalAccess(QObject *parent):
        QObject(parent)
{
   qDebug() << "Loading.......";
   suc = new QValueSpaceSubscriber ("/Allstar/external/", this);
   QObject::connect(suc, SIGNAL( contentsChanged()),this,
                    SLOT( datachanged();) );
   qDebug() << suc->value("/url").toString();
}


void ExternalAccess::datachanged()
{
     //stuff

}
```

I've ran a million cleans/builds ect but it still won't connect to the slot, does anyone know why it may be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `;` inside the SLOT() call.

```
 QObject::connect(suc, SIGNAL( contentsChanged()),this,
                    SLOT( datachanged();) );
```

should be

```
 QObject::connect(suc, SIGNAL( contentsChanged()),this,
                    SLOT( datachanged()) );
```

Also make sure `datachanged()` is declared in `ExternalAccess`. The `this` in your connect call indicates to look in the current object.

Comment: Thanks Thirler, it works now, I can't believe I didn't think of that :o